# $k$ is a field, $f, g \in k[x]$, $h = \mathsf{lcm}(f,g)$, show that $(h) = (f) \cap (g)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

This comes from Rotman, A-3.63. $k[x]$ is the polynomial ring over field $k$, $(f), (g)$, etc. are principle ideals.  If $h = \mathsf{lcm}(f,g)$, then there are $s, t \in k[x]$ such that

$$h = sf = tg$$

Of course any element in $(f) \cap (g)$ is in both $(f)$ and $(g)$, and for this to be true, it must essentially be 'composed' of multiples of $f$ and $g$ and therefore $h$, as lcm, will generate an ideal that contains all such 'compositions'.  But this reasoning is vague at best, what is the proof?

Comment: Are you familiar with the property of the lcm which says that if $p \in k[x]$ is a multiple of $f$ and $p$ is also multiple of $g$ then $p$ is a multiple of $h = \text{lcm}(f,g)$?

Comment: Yeah, it's the connection between ideals and division I was missing.

Comment: Ah I see, glad to see you got it sorted below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f,g$ divide $h$, $h\in (f)\cap (g)$, $(h)\subseteq (f)\cap (g)$.

On the other hand,
if $r\in (f)\cap (g)$, $f, g$ divide $r$, hence
$h$ divides $r$, so $r\in (h)$.

Thus $(h) = (f)\cap (g)$.

Comment: Aha.  The fact that if $x \in (p)$, then $p$ divides $x$ for any $x$, is what I was missing.  Thanks.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).